# Ubuntu server cannot run PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I'm trying to run PostgreSQL after I installed using Brew on Ubuntu 18.10.
I'm facing this problem:

```
brew services start postgresql
sh: 1: list: not found
sh: 1: list: not found
Error: Failure while executing; `'' load -w /home/demo/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist` exited with 1.
```

Cannot resolve it. I tried many solutions online but PostgreSQL doesn't want to run.

Comment: Why are you using brew? Brew is a package manager for MacOS, not for Ubuntu.

Comment: I used linux brew a version for Linux of home brew just for try but also using other ways I got same issue and I will do from scratch the setup

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try apt on Ubuntu.

According to digitalocean's [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04)  , you can install it like this on ubuntu:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Comment: So I did that I have the same error and I need Ubuntu server no Ubuntu

Comment: This tutorial is for server, digital ocean is a cloud platform. Can you try a clean installment? Like do it in a container or a fresh new vm, if you are not fixing problems on production server.

Comment: Yes I will do all from scratch as was unable to fix the issue

Comment: I just installed it successfully on my server, Ubuntu 18.04, to check if the tutorial is working. Can you try a different version of ubuntu?